# How to center elements in Frames and StackLayouts and why the frames expand horizontally after each click of the buttons

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have horizontal `ScrollView`  And inside I have 5 vertical frames. In everyone `StackLayout` I put a image as a background. How can I center the elements in `StackLayout` in every `Frame`.
[image: UnCentered Elements]

I will paste the code from the first frame:

```
 <StackLayout 
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Frame Grid.Column="0"
                                     BorderColor="White"
                                     Margin="10,0,10,0"
                                     CornerRadius="10"
                                     BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <RelativeLayout>
        <Image
            x:Name="ImageForecast1"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                   Property=Height,
                                                                   Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Factor=1}"/>
                            <StackLayout>

                                <Label x:Name="DayForecast1"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           TextColor="#eeff00"/>

                                <Label x:Name="TempDayForecast1"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           TextColor="#eeff00"/>

                                <Label Text="Min °C"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="2"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           TextColor="#00ccff"/>

                                <Label x:Name="MinTempDayForecast1"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="3"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           TextColor="#00ccff"/>

                                <Label Text="Max °C"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="4"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           TextColor="#ff0000"/>

                                <Label x:Name="MaxTempDayForecast1"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="5"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           TextColor="#ff0000"/>

                                <Image x:Name="IconChanceOf5DaysForecast1"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="6"
                                       Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Label x:Name="ChanceOf5DaysForecast1"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="7"
                                           Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Image x:Name="IconWind5DaysForecast1"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="8"
                                       Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].WindForecast.WindForecastValue, StringFormat='{0:0}m/s'}"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="9"
                                           Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Image x:Name="IconClouds5DaysForecast1"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="10"
                                       Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].CloudsForecast.CloudsForecastValue, StringFormat='{0:0}%'}"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="11"
                                           Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Image x:Name="IconRain5DaysForecast1"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="12"
                                       Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].RainForecast.RainForecastValue, StringFormat='{0}mm'}" 
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="13"
                                           Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Image x:Name="IconSnow5DaysForecast1"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="14"
                                       Grid.Column="0"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].SnowForecast.SnowForecastValue, StringFormat='{0}mm'}" 
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Grid.Row="15"
                                           Grid.Column="0"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                          </RelativeLayout>
                        </Frame>
```

I have two questions:

- The first is how to center the elements in each `Frame` and `StackLayout` ?
- My second question is why after each click of a button all the frames expand horizontally and how can I fix this problem?

I will upload a screenshot after a few clicks of a button:
[image: Extend the frame horizontal after button clicks]

Comment: use HorizontalOptions and HorizontalTextAligntment both set to Center.  However, that only centers relative to the parent layout - you have a complex nested layout so you may need to be sure that each sub-element is centered relative to its parent

Comment: Can you give me example where exactly to use HorizontalOptions and HorizontalTextAligntment ?

Comment: on the elements you want centered, and potentially on their parent elements also.  Your layout is too complex to give a specific example by just looking at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first is how to center the elements in each Frame and StackLayout
> ?

Just put in the `StackLayout` the same constraints you have put for the image:

```
<StackLayout RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                    Property=Height,                                                                    
                                                                    Factor=1}"   
             RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                   Property=Width,
                                                                   Factor=1}">
                        
                        <Label x:Name="DayForecast1"

                     ...
</StackLayout>
```

It worked for me:

[image]

> My second question is why after each click of a button all the frames
> expand horizontally and how can I fix this problem?

You already asked that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111899/how-to-stop-horizontal-stretching-of-a-image-using-xamarin/).