# Xamarin.Forms - Frame expanding when Image inside it loaded multiple times

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a  horizontal `<ScrollView/>`. Inside it there is a `<Frame/>` containing an `<Image/>`. The `<Image/>` source is loaded when a button is pressed (see the code for button below). When you press the button multiple times, the `<Frame/>` is stretching each time. For example, if you press the button 5 times, the frame stretches 5 times.

```
<ScrollView 
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout 
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Frame Grid.Column="0"
                                     BorderColor="White"
                                     Margin="10,0,5,0"
                                     CornerRadius="10"
                                     BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <RelativeLayout>
       <Image
            x:Name="ImageDescriptionForecastTest"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                   Property=Height,
                                                                   Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Factor=1}"/>
                            <StackLayout>
                            .....
                            .....
                            </StackLayout>
                         </RelativeLayout>
                       </Frame>
```

When I remove this line of the code:

```
<Image
            x:Name="ImageDescriptionForecastTest"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                   Property=Height,
                                                                   Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Factor=1}"/>
```

and then press the button, nothing stretches and everything works normally.

In the very logic of the button I check weather condition and change the backgrounds accordingly:

```
 if (descriptionForecast1 == "clear sky")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/ClearSky.jpg";
           
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "few clouds")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/FewClouds.jpg";
         
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "scattered clouds")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/Scattering.jpg";
      
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "broken clouds")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/BrokenClouds.jpg";
           
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "light rain")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/LightRain.jpg";
            
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "rain")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/Rain.jpg";
                 
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "thunderstorm")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/Thunderstorm.jpg";
                  
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "snow")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/Snow.jpg";
                   
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "mist")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/Mist.jpg";
                 
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "overcast clouds")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/OverCastClouds.jpg";
                   
                }
                else if (descriptionForecast1 == "moderate rain")
                {
                    ImageDescriptionForecastTest.Source = "Images/ModerateRain.jpg";
             
                }
```

What should I change in this code so that the frame is not stretched?

I have attached a screenshot from simulator  (for example, look at the frame that contains weather info for Thursday):
[image: Stretching Frames]

Comment: What is your button click event? What does the `press the button 5 times, the frame stretches 5 times.` mean? Could you provide more details for me to reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I change in this code so that the frames are not stretched
> ?

You should add appropriate `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` in your `Frame`. For example, something like this (appropriate values you should determine based on source images and the look of the view you want to achieve):

```
<Frame Grid.Column="0"
    HeightRequest="200"
    WidthRequest="50"
    BorderColor="White"
    Margin="10,0,5,0"
    CornerRadius="10"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent">
```

**Edit**:
You can set `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` dynamically, so that is adjustable to the screen size. For example, define `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` in XAML like this:

```
HeightRequest="{Binding heightOfFrame}"
WidthRequest="{Binding widthOfFrame}"
```

Then in your page do something like this (you should set it appropriately):

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public Double heightOfFrame { get; set; }
    public Double widthOfFrame { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Double screenHeigth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
        Double screenWidth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
        
        //This will set the height and width to half of your screen's height and width
        heightOfFrame = screenHeigth/2; //set this as you would like it to be
        widthOfFrame = screenWidth/2; //set this as you would like it to be

        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I set width and height values how can I customise the frames on smaller and biggest display ?

Comment: You can set the values dynamically by doing something like I added in updated part of the answer.

Comment: I try this code not worked for me, still when I click the button frames are extends

Comment: Hm, it works for me. Can you please try adding `this.ForceLayout();` at the end of the `public MainPage()` constructor (after `BindingContext = this` line)?

Comment: Was this a solution for you, I see that you didn't accept this as an answer... Or you found another way to solve this?